# Apple Configurator V1.4 was working this morning, now quits immediately upon start

Tags: mac-mini, apple-configurator

I have a new Mac Mini, OS X 10.8.5 (12F45), just set up this morning.  Downloaded Apple Configurator 1.4 (351).  It worked fine up until about an hour ago, when it started quitting as soon as I start it.  The error message reads, "Apple Configurator quit unexpectedly".

I have rebooted the Mac, deleted and reinstalled the AC, but neither action made any difference.  Seems to be quitting due to an uncaught exception.  Any ideas how to work around this?  Or do I just wait a few days and see if this is magically fixed?  (I.e., a new version is released.)

Comment: When is the last time you made a backup of that Machine? (and now would be a good time to make a snap as well just in case you need it).

Answer (score 2):

1. Delete the Apple Configurator preference file and try running the app again.

   ```
   rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.configurator.plist
   ```
2. Delete the Apple Configurator file containers and try running the app again.

   ```
   sudo find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.configurator -delete
   ```

---

These files *should not* contain any important information regarding your devices and/or settings in Apple Configurator. Both the preferences `.plist` and the containers didn't contain anything important, and after making a backup I ran the above commands on my machine - it didn't cause any problems. All my settings remained in the app.

However, this doesn't necessarily mean it will be the same for you. You can check the contents of the containers by running the following command (I've also included my output so you can compare if you wish):

```
sudo find /private/var/folders -name com.apple.configurator | xargs tree
/private/var/folders/hh/41_x4gjd5sl_fmdsmglz94xw0000gn/C/com.apple.configurator
├── com.apple.scriptmanager.le.cache
└── mds
    ├── mds.lock
    ├── mdsDirectory.db
    └── mdsObject.db
/private/var/folders/hh/41_x4gjd5sl_fmdsmglz94xw0000gn/T/com.apple.configurator
└── TemporaryItems
    └── (A\ Document\ Being\ Saved\ By\ Apple\ Configurator)
3 directories, 4 files
```

---

As per [this Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5194), the Apple Configurator's *actual data* is stored in `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.configurator`. If, once you have followed the instructions above, the app still does not work, backup this folder and delete it. If the app works after you do this, and you need your data back, restore this folder from your most recent backup.

Comment: Does this preserve volume purchase codes and other critical data needed to unlock iPads and iOS devices that are already supervised? (i.e. could you explain the safety or lack thereof of deleting this file for AC 1.4)

Comment: @bmike Yes, it does (as far as I can tell). I've added some 'safety' information to my answer.